# How to multiply matrices of different sizes?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, matrix

I am trying to multiply matrices of different sizes. Generally if the matrix has the same size you would use 2 for loops, but what about matrices with different sizes?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int mat1[2][3] ={{1,2,3},
                  {4,5,6},
                  };
  int mat2[3][2] = {{1,2},
                    {3,4},
                    {6,5}
                   };

int *pointerToMat1 = &mat1[0][0];
int *pointerToMat2 = &mat2[0][0];



  return 0;
}
```

I was thinking to use pointers but I got lost. The above example is just to test the function, in general matrixProduct should work for any size matrices, as long as mathematical rules hold.

Comment: I think you can use a for loop however what do i need to put as a constraint?

Comment: Also two loops of course. How would you do the multiplication on paper?

Comment: [Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition) of `M1(a,b) * M2(c,d)` is well defined when `b==c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. The formula for matrix multiplication is pretty straightforward:

```
Multiplying A(MxN) and B(NxM) gives C(MxM):

C[i,j] = sum ( A[i,k]*B[k,j] k = 0..N ) ; i,j=0..M
```

So with your code I would do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
      int mat1[2][3] ={{1,2,3},
                  {4,5,6},
                  };
      int mat2[3][2] = {{1,2},
                        {3,4},
                        {6,5}
                       };
    
    int *pointerToMat1 = &mat1[0][0];
    int *pointerToMat2 = &mat2[0][0];
    
    
    int C[2][2];
    for ( int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        for( int j=0;j<2;j++ ) {
           C[i][j] = 0;
           for( int k=0;k<3;k++ ) {
               printf("%dx%d=%d\n",mat1[i][k],mat2[k][j],mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j]);
              C[i][j] += mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
           } 
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d %d %d %d",C[0][0],C[0][1],C[1][0],C[1][1]);
    
}
```

Comment: how are you accessing C[i][k] if `k`, hasn't been declared yet ? Also what if we want to use a variable as a constrain in for loop I mean.: ``` for( int j=0;j<variable;j++ )```

Comment: There was a typo, it should be `C[i][j]`

Comment: Yes you can use variables, but the limits are defined by the size of the matrixes, so you use what is correct for your program. If the matrixes have to be dynamically sized you will put variables as limits of the for loop.